# Use XPath expression to find always the last element of a hierarchy of similar element names

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have the following XML structure

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
    <PGR name="Group1">
        <PGR name="SubGroup1.1">
            <PGR name="SubGroup1.2">
                <PRODUCT></PRODUCT>
            </PGR>
        </PGR>
    </PGR>
    <PGR name="Group2">
        <PGR name="SubGroup2.1">
            <PGR name="SubGroup2.2">
                <PGR name="SubGroup2.3">
                    <PRODUCT></PRODUCT>
                </PGR>
            </PGR>
        </PGR>
    </PGR>
</ROOT>
```

I would like to have a XPath expression that returns me the PGR elements named `SubGroup1.2` and `SubGroup2.3`.

Therefore I wrote the following expression I found in another SO

```
evalExpression = "//PGR[count(*)=0]";
```

This does work for the first PGR hierarchy but does not for the second. The result set only has a size of `1` therefore.

Can someone give me an example how this might work out?

**expected result**

A set of `2` that contains `PGR name="SubGroup1.2` & `PGR name="SubGroup2.3`

Comment: Is your test for selecting the target elements determined by the elements' name, their position in the tree or by something else?

Comment: name and position

Comment: I understand the name part, but can you be more specific about the position? Exactly what position relative to where in the tree? And does the element have to meet BOTH conditions - name=x and position=y, or is one of these enough?

Comment: It should be the last `PGR` without any following `PGR` elements as children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you can do is to add a check for having a *direct `PRODUCT` child*:

```
//PGR[./PRODUCT]
```

Or, PGR nodes not having PGR nodes as children:

```
//PGR[not(PGR)]
```

---

The problem with counting `child::*` is that `child` axis takes only direct children into account. You can switch to [`descendant` axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/descendant) instead to check for all the children, grand-children, grand-grand-children etc and require only 1:

```
//PGR[count(descendant::*) = 1]
```

Comment: The latter worked. Can you explain how the expression can be "read"? does the `[ ]` refer to children elements? If yes - can the same be achieved with the `child` axis?

Comment: @xetra11 sure, `[]` is just the syntax for a filter.  The problem with `child` axis is that it counts direct children of a node and does not go deeper. But, on that note, `descendants` should work here: `//PGR[count(descendant::*) = 1]`. Adding to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I am still a bit confused about `[]`. Having `//PGR[not(PGR)]` it reads to me as "If PGR is not PGR" - that does not make sense to me. How is `[not(PGR)]` be applied to the next nested element?

Comment: @xetra11 ah, I think I see what confuses you. `not(PGR)` is the same as `not(./PGR)` - so with `//PGR[not(PGR)]` we are looking for `PGR` nodes not having any other `PGR` nodes as children. Hope this is a bit more clear.

Comment: Ok since `.` refers to the current node and `./PGR` therefore to the next one in the tree (unix style) it makes sense now. Thanks a heap!